# thmtools with thmbox split in two pages

Tags: theorems, thmtools

I am trying to use the `thmbox=M`option from the `thmtools` package. But sometimes in the text when there isn't enough space for the theorem to fit in the bottom of the first page, it moves it to the next page and still splits it further to a third page. I have a minimal example here. I really like the box shape, so if you can give me a solution using the same package, or tell me how to make a boxed theorem like this, I would really appreciate it!

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[style=remark, thmbox=M, name=Theorem]{theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\blindtext[4]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Assuming this is true, 
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:zeroconf}
\sum_{i,j} d_{i,j}^2\|X_i- X_j\|^2=0
\end{equation}
Then this happens.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: p1]

[image: p2]

[image: p3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ultimately, the package `thmbox` is loaded, and that has an option `nocut`.

since you're not calling this package directly, try adding this option to your `\documentclass` line, and hope for the best.  (this tactic did work for your example.)

Comment: The most awesome solution ever proposed to me! Thanks! Can you always pass left out options to through the `\documentclass`?!

Comment: thanks for the "attaboy".  i'm not sure this always works, but i can't remember having gotten any worse complaint than "unused option".  in other words, it's not likely to destroy anything, so it's worth a try, and if it doesn't work, you can always delete it.

Comment: I have the same problem and this solution does not solve the problem. I mean it solves the problem but creates another one. The problem now is that the theorems, lemmas and the rest are placed in such as way that they are not cut (of course), leaving then big empty spaces in many pages. So the problem is that, the bug described here does not seem to be fully resolved using the nocut option.

Comment: @Konuts -- a second question was posted regarding this problem: [thmbox splits theorems in two pages and the option “nocut” produces many empty spaces in pages.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129292/579) some alternate approaches are offered there.