# thmbox splits theorems in two pages and the option "nocut" produces many empty spaces in pages.

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, theorems, thmtools

this is a follow up to the problem described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129247/thmtools-with-thmbox-split-in-two-pages).

I have the same problem and the proposed solution does not completely solve the problem. I mean, it does solve the problem but also creates another one. The new problem is that the theorems, lemmas and the rest are placed in such as way that they are not cut (of course), but this leaves then big empty spaces in many pages. So the problem is that, the problem described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129247/thmtools-with-thmbox-split-in-two-pages) does not seem to be fully resolved using the nocut option.

Do you any of you have a good idea on how to solve this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

This perhaps is not the kind of answer you were expecting. Instead of using the `thmbox=M` option (which relies in the `thmbox` package) from the `thmtools` package , I would suggest you the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package to design a theorem style imitating the one provided by the `M` option, but behaving nicely with page breaks:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ulem}

\makeatletter
\def\tcb@theo@title#1#2#3{%
  \ifdefempty{#2}{\setbox\z@=\hbox{#1}}{\setbox\z@=\hbox{#1~#2}}%
  \def\temp@a{#3}%
  \ifx\temp@a\@empty\relax%
    \unhbox\z@%
  \else%
    \setbox\z@=\hbox{\unhbox\z@\ }%
    \hangindent\wd\z@%
    \hangafter=1%
    \mbox{\unhbox\z@}(#3)%
  \fi%
}
\renewcommand{\newtcbtheorem}[5][]{%
  \newtcolorbox[auto counter,#1]{#2}[3][]{#4,%
    title={\uline{\tcb@theo@title{#3}{\thetcbcounter}{##2}}},
    list entry={\numberline{\thetcbcounter}##2},%
    code={\tcb@theo@label{#5}{##3}},%
    ##1}%
}
\makeatother

\newtcbtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{
breakable,
enhanced,
arc=0pt,
outer arc=0pt,
coltitle=black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
fontupper=\itshape,
colback=white,
colframe=white,
left=30pt,
lefttitle=0pt,
boxsep=0pt,
right=0pt,
overlay unbroken={
  \draw ([xshift=15pt,yshift=-11pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=15pt]frame.south west) |- +(30pt,0);},
overlay first={
  \draw ([xshift=15pt,yshift=-11pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=15pt]frame.south west);},
overlay middle={
  \draw ([xshift=15pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=15pt]frame.south west);},
overlay last={
  \draw ([xshift=15pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=15pt]frame.south west) |- +(30pt,0);},
before=\vspace{2ex}\noindent,
}{the}

\begin{document}

Some cross referecens to theorems~\ref{the:testa} and~\ref{the:testb}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{theorem}{}{testa}
\lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}{}{testb}
\lipsum[4]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you want to stay with `thmbox`, you can make use of the internal switch that allows or prevents a page break in the middle of a theorem.

since it's unlikely that *all* theorems will fall in a place that isn't affected by a page break, it's probably useful to make two user-level switches -- one to turn breaking off, and one to turn it on:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cutthmoff}{\thmbox@cutfalse}
\newcommand{\cutthmon}{\thmbox@cuttrue}
\makeatother
```

then you can use these switches either "locally" -- enclosing the desired switch
in a brace-group or `\begingroup ... \endgroup` that surrounds the theorem,
to operate on only that theorem -- or by switching on and off as appropriate.

it is probably a good idea, if your document is in multiple files, to restore
the "normal" setting at the end of each file, to avoid surprises later.