# What is this fancy theorem environment?

Tags: theorems

I'm trying to remake this fancy theorem/definition/lemma environnment, but I've got no any where to begin. Is it a known package or rather a homemade redesign?

[image: Fancy definition environment]

Comment: There is a package that produces that, well, not so brilliant output, but I’ll keep the secret. 

Comment: Ah that's a bummer (but if you have better ideas for package, I'm all ear out)

Comment: Have a look at the 'tcolorbox' package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `thmbox` package, the [manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/thmbox/thmbox.pdf) contains several examples, but for completeness I have included a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmbox}

\newtheorem[M]{proposition}{Proposition}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{proposition}
  Let $M$ be a martingale, then $(\phi(M_t))_{t \geq 0}$ is a
  sub-martingale for all convex functions $\phi$ such that $\phi(M_t)$
  is integrable for all $t$.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proof}
  This follows from Jensen's inequality for conditional expectations,
  see any standard text book on this subject.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Do note that the proof is environment is also redefined. There are two additional styles L and S. The package is rather old and might have problems concerning page breaks. So as the comments suggest, implementing the style in another package might be a better solution—[this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129308/167015) implements the M style in the powerful `tcolorbox` package.