# How to prevent thmbox from rendering over page number

Tags: thmbox

I'm using `thmbox` and it seems it does not properly understand page size.
When it splits a box between pages, sometimes it writes over the page number.
Is this an error in my document, or is it that `extreport` does not play well with `thmbox`, or is this simply a bug in thmbox?   Is there a way I can fix it?   If I completely turn of cutting as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129247/thmtools-with-thmbox-split-in-two-pages), it no longer writes over the page number, but it now refuses to cut boxes
between pages, which is not good for long theorems, etc.

I'm including a pretty small working example.  It is difficult to produce a really short example at it seems to be triggered by long documents.   This LaTeX code produces a 5 page document.   You can see the error at the bottom of page 4 where the definition of *determinant* cuts between pages, and the page number (4) is written over by the math formula.  $a_{1k}$

[image: Formula writes over page number]

Here is a zoomed out view of the confused definition.

[image: Definition with theorem box]

I also notice the math equation falls outside the theorem box.
Perhaps it is something to do with `extreport` and math mode?  However, I only see then problem with equations inside the box.

```latex
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmbox}

\newtheorem[bodystyle=\normalfont\noindent]{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem[bodystyle=\normalfont\noindent]{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\newcommand\jleft{\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\left}
\newcommand\jright{\aftergroup\egroup\right}
\newcommand\jparen[1]{\jleft(#1\jright)}
\newcommand\supress[2]{{\mathfrak{S}_{#2}\jparen{#1}}}
\newcommand\cvec[1]{\begin{bmatrix} #1 \end{bmatrix}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{{\left| #1 \right|}}

\title{Practical Linear Algebra}
\author{Jim Newton}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Matrices}
\label{ch.matrices}
\section{Definition}

What is a matrix?

\begin{enumerate}
\item Mathematical definition.
\item Representing in Python
\end{enumerate}

\section{Addition}

Matrices are added component-wise.
If two matrices $A$ and $B$ each have dimensions $n\times m$, i.e., $n$ rows and $m$ columns,
then the can be added and the compnent in the row $i$ column $j$ of the sum
is exactly $c_{ij}=a_{ij}+b_{ij}$.
\begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1m}\\
    a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots&a_{2m}\\
    \vdots & \vdots &&\vdots\\
    a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\cdots&a_{nn}
  \end{bmatrix} +
  \begin{bmatrix}
    b_{11} & b_{12}  &\cdots & b_{1n}\\
    b_{21} & b_{22}  &\cdots & b_{2n}\\
    \vdots & \vdots &       & \vdots\\
    b_{n1}  & b_{n2} &\cdots & b_{nn}
  \end{bmatrix} =\\
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}+b_{11} & a_{12}+b_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n}+b_{1n}\\
    a_{21}+b_{21} & a_{22}+b_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n}+b_{2n}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & &\vdots\\
    a_{n1}+b_{n1} & a_{n2}+b_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}+b_{nn}
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Matrix addition is commutative when the components are themselves
commutative.  For example if the components are integers or real
numbers.

The $n\times m$ zero matrix is the additive identity for the set of $n\times m$ matrices.

\section{Multiplication}
Two matrices, $A$ and $B$, can be multiplied if their dimensions are
compatible.  The requirement is that an $n\times k$ (on the left) can
be multiplied by a $k \times n$ matrix to obtain an $n\times m$
matrix.

Matrix multiplication is, in general, not commutative.  However, there
do exist pairs of matricies which are commutative under
multiplication.  E.g., $A^n \times A^m = A^{n+m} = A^{m+n} = A^m\times
A^n$.  Also if a matrix is invertable, then $A \times A^{-1} = I =
A^{-1}\times A$.

We may multiply two matricies
\begin{align*}
  A &= \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1k}\\
    a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots&a_{2k}\\
    \vdots & \vdots &&\vdots\\
    a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\cdots&a_{nk}
  \end{bmatrix}\\
  B &=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    b_{11} & b_{12}  &\cdots & b_{1n}\\
    b_{21} & b_{22}  &\cdots & b_{2n}\\
    \vdots & \vdots &       & \vdots\\
    b_{k1}  & b_{k2} &\cdots & b_{kn}
  \end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
to obtain a matrix with dimensions $n\times m$, and the component
$c_{ij}$, row $i$, column $j$, is exactly
\begin{equation}
  c_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{k}a_{ik}b_{kj}
\end{equation}

There are many ways to think about this.  One way is that we
\emph{multiply} the rows of $A$ by the columns of $B$.  Another way to
think about it is that each $c_{ij}$ is the dot product of two
vectors, the i'th row vector from $A$ with the j'th column vector of
$B$.  The dot product of two vectors having the same dimension is:
\begin{equation}
  \cvec{a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_n} \cdot   \cvec{b_1\\b_2\\\vdots\\b_n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_kb_k\,.
\end{equation}


There is an identity matrix for multiplication provided the matrices in question are square.
The identity matrix is denoted $I$
\begin{equation}
  I = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots &  0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots &  0 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &  \vdots  \\
 0 & 0 &  0     & \cdots     &    1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

For any square matrix $A$, we have $I\times A = A\times I = A$.

\section{Determinant}
We will present a method to compute the \emph{determinant} of a square
matrix, called the \emph{Laplacian expansion} method.

The determinant of a matrix which tells us whether the matrix has an
inverse.  Some square matrices have an inverse and some do not.  If
$\det\jparen{A}\ne 0$, then there exists a matrix, which we denote
$A^{-1}$, for which $A\times A^{-1} = A^{-1}A = I$.  The inverse of a
matrix is compute intensive to calculate. In Chapter 3
we will begin talking about ways of computing the inverse.

Given an $n\times m$ matrix:
\begin{equation}
  A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1m}\\
    a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots&a_{2m}\\
    \vdots & \vdots &\ddots&\vdots\\
    a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\cdots&a_{nm}
  \end{bmatrix}\,,
\end{equation}
we first define $\supress{A}{i,j}$ as the $(n-1) \times (m-1)$ matrix
formed by supressing the i'th row and j'th column of $A$.


\begin{definition}[determinant]\label{def.determinant}
We may define the determinant of a square, $n\times n$  matrix as:
\begin{equation}
  \det\jparen{A} = \begin{cases}
    a_{11} & \text{if } n = 1\\
    \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k a_{1k} \det\jparen{\supress{A}{1,k}} & \text{if } n > 1
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

We may also denote $\det\jparen{A}$ as $\abs{A}$.
\end{definition}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Page breaking problem

I don't know if this answer is what you are looking for. The post you linked has a followup question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129292/thmbox-splits-theorems-in-two-pages-and-the-option-nocut-produces-many-empty-s), where the OP wanted a solution to the problem without using the `nocut` option.

As suggested there, I think you should use `tcolorbox` rather than `thmbox`, as his breaking algorithm is more sophisticated.

By replacing the lines:

```latex
\usepackage{thmbox}

\newtheorem[bodystyle=\normalfont\noindent]{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem[bodystyle=\normalfont\noindent]{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
```

With the following code:

```latex
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newlength{\thmboxvlineindent}
\setlength{\thmboxvlineindent}{\dimexpr21.14975pt-0.4em-0.3pt}

\tcbset{
    thmbox/.style={
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners=all,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        fontupper=\normalfont,
        top=0mm,
        bottom=0mm,
        right=0mm,
        left=\dimexpr\thmboxvlineindent-0.3pt,
        boxsep=0.4em,
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
        colbacktitle=white,
        coltitle=black,
        attach boxed title to top left,
        boxed title style={empty, size=minimal, bottom=2.5pt},
        before upper={\parindent=21.14975pt\noindent},
        left skip=\parskip,
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] ([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.north west)--([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.south west)--++(0:0.3pt);
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] ([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.south west)--++(0:1cm);},
        overlay first={
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] ([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.north west)--([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] ([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.north west)--([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] ([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.north west)--([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.south west)--++(0:0.3pt);
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] ([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.south west)--++(0:1cm);}
    }
}

\newcounter{theorem}[section]
\renewcommand*\thetheorem{\thesection.\arabic{theorem}}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]
{thm}
{Theorem \thetheorem}
{thmbox,description font=\itshape,description delimiters={{\normalfont\bfseries(}}{\normalfont\bfseries)},separator sign none}{}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=thm]
{defn}
{Definition \thetheorem}
{thmbox,description font=\itshape,description delimiters={{\normalfont\bfseries(}}{\normalfont\bfseries)},separator sign none}{}


\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]{\refstepcounter{theorem}\csname thm*\endcsname{#1}{}}{\endthm}
\newenvironment{definition}[1][]{\refstepcounter{theorem}\csname defn*\endcsname{#1}{}}{\enddefn}
```

You should be able to use you theorems environment with the same syntax inside the document body.

The code is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236230/264024), but should have the same dimensions (same line thickness, same margins etc.) and same title format as your original theorems.

### Another solution

You can also use tcolorbox's for the theorem environment. The syntax of starting a theorem is `\begin{<env name>}{<theorems title>}{label}`. Although these are mandatory arguments, they can be left empty.

The last argument of the decleration of `tcbtheorem` defines a prefix to the label of the theorem. In the following code i will add a def. prefix to labels of definition environment, (also the dot will be automatic). with this code the definition in your example should be started with `\begin{definition}{determinant}{determinant}`, and to reference it you should use `\ref{def.determinant}`.

```
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newlength{\thmboxvlineindent}
\setlength{\thmboxvlineindent}{\dimexpr21.14975pt-0.4em-0.3pt}

\tcbset{
    thmbox/.style={
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners=all,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        fontupper=\normalfont,
        top=0mm,
        bottom=0mm,
        right=0mm,
        left=\dimexpr\thmboxvlineindent-0.3pt,
        boxsep=0.4em,
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
        colbacktitle=white,
        coltitle=black,
        attach boxed title to top left,
        boxed title style={empty, size=minimal, bottom=2.5pt},
        before upper={\parindent=21.14975pt\noindent},
        left skip=\parskip,
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] ([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.north west)--([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.south west)--++(0:0.3pt);
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] ([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.south west)--++(0:1cm);},
        overlay first={
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] ([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.north west)--([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] ([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.north west)--([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] ([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.north west)--([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.south west)--++(0:0.3pt);
            \draw[line width=0.6pt] ([xshift=\thmboxvlineindent]frame.south west)--++(0:1cm);}
    }
}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]
{theorem}
{Theorem}
{thmbox,description font=\itshape,description delimiters={{\normalfont\bfseries(}}{\normalfont\bfseries)},separator sign none,label separator=.}{theo} % the last argument here, i.e. "theo", is the prefix for the label.
\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=theorem]
{definition}
{Definition}
{thmbox,description font=\itshape,description delimiters={{\normalfont\bfseries(}}{\normalfont\bfseries)},separator sign none,label separator=.}{def}
```

### Equation outside of theorem box

Generally TeX does not break display math equation, so it is not a problem with `extreport`. If you want to write wide display math equation you should use for example the `align` environment provided by `amsmath` package.

Comment: @Uti Fogiel Are you sure the numbering works for the LaTeX code you've included above.   I get that the theorems and definitions display their numbers correctly; however in text \ref{mylabel} always renders as the section number, rather than as the definition, or theorem number.  Do I need to create a mwe to demonstrate?

Comment: @JimNewton, I've fixed the problem in my code. I also added another suggestion (the code is similar, but you might find the syntax to be simpler).

Comment: note that with the second solution you cant label your theorems with `\label` and should only use the theorem argument to do so.

Comment: I've experimented a bit with your solution and it seems to work.  Many thanks for your contribution.